# Should the singleton methods be synchronized?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, singleton, spring-ioc

My web-app (the is no Spring-MVC here, only core IOC) using a lot of prototype beans and most of them are using a singleton dao-bean. Should the singleton dao-bean methods be synhronized since many different prototype beans (from different requests) may use the same method id dao in the same moment?

For example, the dao method

```
public void setLetterNotNew(int letterId) {

    final String sql = "UPDATE income SET isnew=? WHERE id=?";

    try( Connection con = HikariFactory.getConnection(); PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql); ) {

        ps.setInt(1, 0);
        ps.setInt(2, letterId);

        int i = ps.executeUpdate();
        if(i==0) throw new SQLException("setLetterNotNew");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends how you're updating the DB.  Many frameworks are already synchronized so you don't have to do any additional work.  Check your docs.

Comment: @markspace The is no any frameworks here ecxept of spring-ioc. This is a servlet based web-app. The database is updating via standart jdbc.

Comment: yea, you should make the methods of the singleton synchronized or at least the part that it's going to the DB between a synchronized block. Also check how you are planning to build and get the singleton so you don't end up with two instances

Comment: synchronization is needed if multiple threads access shared mutable state. We have no idea what your "update database here" does. If it gets a connection from a datasource, does its jow and closes the connection, then synchronization isn't needed. Since you already use Spring, you should definitely use its declarative transactional support and its JDBC related classes (JdbcTemplate, etc.). Maybe you already do, but since you posted no code...

Comment: @Rumal Creating a singleton is the task for Spring so I do not think we must worry about it.

Comment: @JBNizet I updated the question also see my comment for details in the answer of Rafał S. I use standart jdbc operations for now and not using JdbcTemplate or other database related tools of Spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

As you wrote in a comment, you use jdbc. All operations on JDBC API [are synchronized](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a83724/tips1.htm) and do [auto-commit by default](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-transactions.htm). So if you share your JDBC connection but your method doesn't need a transaction (for example it doesn't do an update on data that was selected few lines before) than it doesn't need to be synchronized.

However, if you need transactions, than you either have to synchronize this method or provide each thread with it's own JDBC connection, as [each connection is also a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186596/tutorial-about-using-multi-threading-in-jdbc). To achieve that you could open new connection each time in a method or let [Spring handle that problem](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)

Comment: How can I define if the method need a transaction? I updated the question. I get Connection from pool (a static method HikariFactory.getConnection()) and the connections closes automatically. Also I know that Jdbc handle multihreading at database level. So the method in question does not contains any state. In this case how can multithreading do wrong things? Actually I think the best idea is using prototype for Dao-bean then there is no need to worry about multitheading.

Comment: If the method does not contain any state than you are safe to use it as it is without changing dao to prototype bean nor synchronizing it. If your statement is a single update, than no transaction is needed. Transactions are used to make sure that multiple queries used at the same time work on the same data from database. In your case there is only one statement so there is no problem.